# how to do field level resolvers using graphql-kotlin with ktor framework

Tags: kotlin, graphql-java, ktor

how to do field level(non root) resolvers using gaphql-kotlin ? My code working *(date_range in API1Response is null as i dont know how to call my second resolver function getAPI2Response() when date_range exists in query)* when each query called separately as i have two suspend functions with concern query names, but i want to call two suspend functions with one query based on a field(non root) check in query. For example, in below shown code (service), if my query is "getAPI1Response" with fields "name","id","date_range", then graphql should call getAPI1Response and also getAPI2Response and map it to Data model "API1Response" so users can use single query instead firing two queries.

Checked few samples from graphql-kotlin samples but all are referring to springboot which i am not using.

```
//DATA MODEL

data class API1Response(
    val name: String?,
    val id: Int?,
    val date_range: API2Response?
)

data class API2Response(
    val max_date_range: ZonedDateTime?,
    val min_date_range: ZonedDateTime?
)
```

```
//SERVICE
class Query() {
    private val httpClient = HttpClient()

// when query name is "getAPI1Response", this function get triggers
    suspend fun getAPI1Response(): API1Response {
        // call API 1 and map response to API1Response model.
        return resp.content.toInputStream().use {
                    jackson.readValue(it, API1Response::class.java)
                }
    }

//// when query name is "getAPI2Response", this function get triggers
    suspend fun getAPI2Response(): API2Response {
        // call API 2 and map response to API2Response model.
        return resp.content.toInputStream().use {
                    jackson.readValue(it, API2Response::class.java)
                }
    }
}
```

```
// GRAPHQL HANDLER

package com.my.package.graphql

import com.expedia.graphql.SchemaGeneratorConfig
import com.expedia.graphql.TopLevelObject
import com.expedia.graphql.hooks.SchemaGeneratorHooks
import com.expedia.graphql.toSchema
import com.my.package.errors.ErrorType
import com.my.package.http.*
import com.my.package.json.Jackson
import graphql.ExecutionInput
import graphql.GraphQL
import graphql.language.StringValue
import graphql.schema.*
import graphql.schema.idl.SchemaPrinter
import io.ktor.application.ApplicationCall
import io.ktor.application.call
import io.ktor.http.ContentType
import io.ktor.http.HttpStatusCode
import io.ktor.response.respondText
import io.ktor.routing.Route
import io.ktor.routing.get
import io.ktor.routing.post
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter
import kotlin.reflect.KClass
import kotlin.reflect.KType

class GraphQLHandler(
    mutations: List<Any>,
    queries: List<Any>
) : Handler {
    private val schema = toSchema(
        config = SchemaGeneratorConfig(
            supportedPackages = listOf("com.my.package"),
            hooks = CustomSchemaGeneratorHooks(),
            topLevelQueryName = "Query",
            topLevelMutationName = "Mutation"
        ),
        mutations = mutations.map { TopLevelObject(it) },
        queries = queries.map { TopLevelObject(it) }
    )

    private val graphQL = GraphQL.newGraphQL(schema).build()

    override val path = "/graphql"

    override val routes: Route.() -> Unit = {
        post {
            postQuery(call)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun postQuery(call: ApplicationCall) {
        val reqBody = call.receiveJson(Map::class)
        val query = reqBody["query"] as? String
        if (query == null) {
            call.respondError(
                HttpStatusCode.BadRequest,
                ErrorType.bad_request,
                "missing or invalid query field in json"
            )
            return
        }

        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        val variables = reqBody["variables"] as? Map<String, Any> ?: emptyMap()

        handleQuery(call, query, variables)
    }

// main function which calls my concern suspend funciton mapping query name to function name
    private suspend fun handleQuery(call: ApplicationCall, query: String, variables: Map<String, Any>?) {
        val executionInput = ExecutionInput(query, null, call.request.authContext, null, variables)
        val result = graphQL.execute(executionInput).toSpecification()
        val statusCode = if (result.containsKey("errors")) HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError else HttpStatusCode.OK
        call.respondJson(statusCode, result, Jackson.all)
    }
}

class CustomSchemaGeneratorHooks : SchemaGeneratorHooks {
    override fun willGenerateGraphQLType(type: KType): GraphQLType? = when (type.classifier as? KClass<*>) {
        ZonedDateTime::class -> graphqlZonedDateTimeType
        LocalDate::class -> graphqlLocalDateType
        else -> null
    }
}

val graphqlLocalDateType = GraphQLScalarType("LocalDate",
    " ISO date format without an offset, such as '2011-12-03' ",
    object : Coercing<LocalDate, String> {
        //override few functions here
    }
)

val graphqlZonedDateTimeType = GraphQLScalarType("ZonedDateTime",
    " ISO date-time format with an offset, such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00' ",
    object : Coercing<ZonedDateTime, String> {
        //override few functions here
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

This has been answered in the associated github issue:
https://github.com/ExpediaDotCom/graphql-kotlin/issues/230

> Example using Spring:
>   https://github.com/ExpediaDotCom/graphql-kotlin/blob/master/example/src/main/kotlin/com/expedia/graphql/sample/query/SubQueries.kt
>
> Since graphql-kotlin reflectively generates resolvers, you'll have to do something like the above example, or use KGraphQL or graphql-java directly
>
> Another example to get the data from further up the query chain is to use the DataFetcherEnvironment. It was added here: [#173](https://github.com/ExpediaDotCom/graphql-kotlin/pull/173)

Answer (score 0):

This question was posted in our issues: https://github.com/ExpediaDotCom/graphql-kotlin/issues/230

We answered there but the best way to access data from fields higher up is through the `DataFetcherEnvironment`. It was added here: https://github.com/ExpediaDotCom/graphql-kotlin/pull/173

Then you can have a function inside of the `API1Response` which will be run when called from the GraphQL schema

```
data class API1Response(
    val name: String?,
    val id: Int?
) {
    // Functions are also exposed as fields.
    // environment will not show up in the schema but be available at runtime.
    fun date_range(environment: DataFetchingEnvironment): API2Response? {
        // Somehow get dates from other args or further up the query chain
        return API2Response()
    }
}
```